# Blueprism To Sort Excel

Tags: excel, vba, blueprism

I am trying to sort a column in excel using Blueprism. I have enhanced the Excel VBO with the following code

```
GetInstance(handle).Sort.SortFields.Add2 (Key:=Range(Range))
```

The code compiles, but when I run it I get the following error

```
Internal : Could not execute code stage because exception thrown by code stage: Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC
```

Comment: what is the value of the range you're passing? it could have something to do with zero based vs 1 based ranges.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GetInstance(handle)` returns only the instance of [`Excel.Application`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application(object)) mapped to that `handle`. `Excel.Application` doesn't have a `Sort` property.

Use a property of the instance like `ActiveSheet` to apply the operation to a sheet (which has a `Sort` property):

```
GetInstance(handle).ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add2 (Key:=Range(Range))
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hi,
In order to use sort functionality in Blue Prism, please use the below code in code stage:**

```
Dim worksheet,Excel As Object

Dim rRng as Object

Dim Header1 as integer

try

Excel = GetWorkbook(handle,Nothing)

worksheet = GetWorkbook(handle,Nothing).ActiveSheet

rRng = worksheet.Range(Data_StartCell,Data_EndCell)

if HeaderPresent = true then

    Header1=1

else if HeaderPresent = false then

    Header1=2

end if

rRng.Sort(Key1:=worksheet.Range(Order_StartCell,Order_EndCell), Order1:=OrderType,Header:=Header1)

Success = true

catch e as Exception

Success = false

End try
```

**Input Variables Used**- handle , Data_StartCell , Data_EndCell, Order_StartCell, Order_EndCell, OrderType, HeaderPresent

**Output Variables -** Success

Suppose you want have data from A1:E20 column and you need to sort column B only. So below are the inputs which you can use:

**Data_StartCell**- "A1"

**Data_EndCell** - "E20"

**Order_StartCell**- "B1"

**Order_EndCell**- "B20"

**OrderType**- 1 (it is of Number type and 1 for Ascending and 2 for Descending)

**HeaderPresent**- True or False depending you have headers or not

Hope the solution works for you.